# How to merge two 1-row tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on some SQL queries at the moment, and currently wanted to take the averages of two different queries and merge them into a 2-column, 1-row table.

For instance, I have the result of one query that has avg_cookies and a value of 10, and another result that is avg_cakes and a value of two.

I was thinking of using a UNION to merge the two, however the result is a 1-column, 2-row table, and that's not quite what I'm going for.

Is there a way to slam two SQL tables together with unrelated columns?

Comment: You can just `JOIN` them, but they'll need something in common, that's how RDBMS work. Not sure what you're going for here, can you provide more detail?

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected result?  Your wording is confusing me here on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
SELECT
  (SELECT AVG(Cookies) FROM Cookies) AS avg_cookies,
  (SELECT AVG(Cakes) FROM Cakes) AS avg_cakes
```

Comment: Thanks was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I think cross-join is the way to go..

```
select
    avg(Cookies.CookieCount) AverageCookies
    , avg(Cakes.CakeCount) AverageCakes
from
    dbo.Cookies
    cross join dbo.Cakes
```